# Unity increment velocity based on interval

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to get a background to start moving to the left faster and faster. 
Was thinking of using two values one for the amount in percent to increase and one value for the interval between incrementing which would also get larger the more times an interval is hit?

```
public float interval = 1; // 1 second between intervals starting off
public float speed = 2; // the starting speedi

void Start () {
    // move left
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.left * speed;
}

void Update () {
// check if interval has been reached? How?

//if interval has been reached then ( This does not work for me..
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity * 0.01f;
    interval = interval * 2;
}
```

Comment: *0.01f makes object slower and slower. try *1.01 instead of it.

Comment: @Pete Is your background in a loop (repeating)?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a few things you need to fix here:

1.) you are multiplying velocity by .01 every frame, this will practically freeze it completely. I'm not sure what you mean to do by that.

2.) You are calling GetComponent>Rigidbody2D<() every frame, which is very expensive! You should create a variable for it something like:

```
Rigidbody2d RB;
void Start () {
    RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

For how to increase speed after each interval, I might declare a counter which you increase every frame. And if the counter > interval then interval *= 2 and counter = 0

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all take `Rigidbody2D` in a variable once then play with it.

You can use `Coroutine` for this purpose.

```
public float interval = 1; // 1 second between intervals starting off
public float speed = 2; // the starting speed

Rigidbody2D _rb;

void Start () {
    // move left
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    _rb.velocity = Vector2.left * speed;
    StartCoroutine("IncreaseSpeedWithInterval");
}

void Update () {

}

IEnumerator IncreaseSpeedWithInterval()
{
    while(true){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);

    // Now either Multiply your velocity by 1.01f or Add by 0.01f
    _rb.velocity *= 1.01f;
    // ========== OR ========== //
    _rb.velocity += (Vector2.one * 0.01f);
    }
}
```